# validates password on user model not working in edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a bit confused.  Before I added email validation functionality to my sample app, my validation looked like this in the /app/models/user.rb:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Once I implemented my signup email confirmation functionality, I needed to add this to the validation:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :validates_password?
...
def validates_password?
    password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```

because I would get a validation error when the user clicked on the link inside the email to verify their email address.  Upon making this change to the password validation, my email worked!  However, my test for the invalid information in my edit action of the users controller began to fail.  Then I noticed that the edit form no longer has an error even though they do not type the password in.  So I added some debug statements that you can see in the image below:
[image]

"user password present" is evaluated as `@user.password.present?`

"user password_confirmation present" is evaluated as `@user.password_confirmation.present?`

"user is valid" is evaluated as `@user.valid?`

"validate_password?" is evaluated as `@user.password.present? || @user.password_confirmation.present?`

How is this happening?  How is my user valid by passing `valid?` but the `validate_password?` method is returning false???

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  `@user.valid?` **should** be `true` when both `user.password` and `user.password_confirmation` are blank.

Comment: It lets me update the user without me putting a password into the form.  I think I don't understand what password.present? does.  If you have an existing user and the password is empty, shouldn't it be NOT valid?

Comment: The way most Edit User forms work is they allow the user to update their account without a password.  However, if the user puts in a password and password_confirmation, the form will then validate those fields and update the user's password.

Comment: That's how I felt too when I went through the tutorial at [link](http://www.railstutorial.org/chapters) but there was a test written that expects an error flash message if you just click on the `submit` button without filling out anything.  Is it worth it to just take that test out?

Comment: `var.present?` means "is `var` not blank?".  Literally the function definition for `present?` is `!blank?`.

Comment: I undestand what `present?` means.  What I am confused about is how the validation passes if the body of the method `validate_password?` returns false.

Comment: `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :validates_password?` is saying "I'm going to validate the password length if `validates_password?` is true.  If the user doesn't fill in password/password_confirmation, then `validates_password?` is false so `validates: password` never fires.  That's what is happening in this case.

Comment: OHHH okay.  Thank you so much!  That makes way more sense.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From the comments:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :validates_password?
```

is saying "I'm going to make sure the password length is a minimum of 6 characters if `validates_password?` is `true`.

If the user doesn't fill in password/password_confirmation, then `validates_password?` is `false` so:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :validates_password?
```

never fires. That's what is happening in this case.